# Where can I find -arch options doc for mac gcc?

Tags: objective-c, gcc

The link here [Apple's gcc, what's the difference between -arch i386 and -m32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754460/apples-gcc-whats-the-difference-between-arch-i386-and-m32) 
is not valid any more.

And searching on apple site is astoundingly difficult: I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

How about the gcc man page?  `% man gcc`

Comment: Thanks will try but I'm not used to mac and linux. I prefer doc online which is more pretty and may contain more explanations :)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gcc.1.html

Answer (score 2):

Most (all?) man pages are available at Apple’s Web site, too: [gcc man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gcc.1.html)

-arch is an Apple GCC-specific option that tells the compiler to generate code for *all* architectures specified with -arch, e.g. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 will produce fat binaries targeted at both 32-bit and 64-bit Intel, whereas only one of -m32, -m64 is used by the compiler.

Comment: seems their man page doesn't seem to list the correct allowable values for -march, for instance. Odd.