# Unknown Objective-C error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64," everything seems OK

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here:

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000081.php

And soon as I reached the "Header files" section, I kept getting a strange error message after running `gcc test1.c -o test1` in the Mac OSX command line:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sum", referenced from:
      _main in ccdZyc82.o
  "_average", referenced from:
      _main in ccdZyc82.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

math_functions.h:

```
int sum(int x, int y);
float average(float x, float y, float z);
```

math_functions.c:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}

float average(float x, float y, float z) {
  return (x + y + z)/3;
}
```

And finally, my test1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math_functions.h"

main() {
  int thesum = sum(1, 2);
  float ave = average(1.1, 2.21, 55.32);

  printf("sum = %i\nave = %f\n(int)ave = %i\n", thesum, ave, (int)ave);
}
```

I seem to have followed everything correctly and I don't understand where that error is coming from. Help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754460/apples-gcc-whats-the-difference-between-arch-i386-and-m32

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate source files, math_functions.c and test1.c, they both need to be compiled, and linked together. The error messages tells you that the compiler doesn't find the functions `average` and `float` and that is because they come from math_functions.c and you only compiled test1.c.

The example you linked to tells you to type:

```
gcc test3.c math_functions.c -o test3
```

Comment: I knew it! And all I had to do was scroll down some more.

Answer (score 1):

You are not linking in the object file that contain the `sum()` and `average()` functions.

Do this:

```
$ gcc -c -o math_functions.o math_functions.c
$ gcc -c -o test1.o test1.c
$ gcc -o test1 test1.o math_functions.o
```

The first two lines compile the source files into object files and the final line links the object files into the executable file.

You need to invest some time learning `make`, as no developer can be bother to type that much just to compile (also before you know it you've got the filenames wrong and compiled over your source file!).